# Jquery: Perform an event according to browser size

Tags: jquery

On my website, I want paragraphs to be turned into an accordion menu when the browser view port size becomes less than 480px.

This is the code I am using to achieve that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();  
    if ( pageWidth <= 480 ) {

$('.data > h3').addClass('jqlink');
$('.data ').addClass('jqbg');
$('.data>h3').append('<p>[+]</p>');
   $('.data > p').hide();   //hide the event 

   $('.data > h3').click(function(){   //clicked on the title
       if($(this).next().is(':visible')){      //is this question already visible?
        $(this).next().hide('fast');           //hide it (toggle)
       }else{   
        $('.data > p:visible').hide('fast');    //otherwise, hide whatever is currently visible
        $(this).next().show('fast');                    //show the question we clicked on
       }
   });

 } });
```

It works brilliantly, except it only triggers when the browser first loads.
If the browser is re-sized after loading, then the code wont work.

I know of the [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) command. However, that only seems to work if the browser is resized. If the browser is less than 480px when it first loads, then the code will only trigger if the user resizes the browser.

How can I get the code to work both on resize and on browser load?

Comment: The code you have above doesn't trigger on browser load?

Comment: The OP wants it to trigger both on browser load and browser resize

Comment: You can use standard CSS Media Types http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html and Media Queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ for a lot of that work of resizing, for example to target different layouts, without any JavaScript; then layer JavaScript on top for the remaining needed behaviour.  This blog post provides some sample insight into Media Queries and JavaScript used together to achieve the outcome http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/ Your page might be unnecessarily JavaScript heavy depending on what browsers you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkWindowSize() {
   var pageWidth = $(window).width();  
   if ( pageWidth <= 480 ) {

   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWindowSize();
    $(window).resize(checkWindowSize);  
});
```

Should do the trick and prevents duplication of your code ...

Comment: This is great. But the only problem is that each time the browser menu moves past 480px, the accordion menu is added to the page. So for example, by the time the browser is re-sized from 480px to 470px, 10 menus appear! Is there anyway around this(so the menu only appears once)? I guess I am looking for the equivalent of CSS media queries for Jquery.

Comment: Just check if the accordion already exists before adding it !!! Add your accordion code to the question

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for the code. However, I have added the accordion code to the opening post. Thanks for your continued help!

Answer (score 0):

See the **[.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** method.

Here's an **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QcmpG/1)**, or the **[full window version](http://jsfiddle.net/QcmpG/1/embedded/result/)**

In this example, you first check for window size when the document first loads, and then listen to window changes and wait for it to drop below 480px.

EDIT: I've updated my example to include a variable and a condition to make sure the required action only happens once.

Comment: This is great, but it also has the same problem as ManseUK's solution. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @big_smile simply add a condition on whether the accordion exists or not. I'll add it to my example...

Comment: Thanks for your continued help! In the JSFiddle example, the text just says False, no matter how much you resize the window.

Comment: JSfiddle works on frames, resize the frame in this case, not the window. I'll add a full-window result page @big_smile .

Answer (score 0):

On page load you can use media queries in modernizr: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#mq

if(Modernizr.mq('only all and (max-width:      480px)'){

//init your accord

}

This will setup according for all viewports under 480px on page load. For resize, use the resize() you mentioned